Clash with minted and hyperref?
With this MRE, I noticed few bizarre side effects...

If hyperref is loaded any mintinline that contains # inside an item will fail
If hyperref is not loaded, the # inside the mintinline inside the item[] is doubled.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}
%\usepackage{hyperref} % Fails if enabled
\begin{document}

\mintinline{c}|#include|

\begin{description}
  \item[\mintinline{c}|#include|] Foobar
\end{description}

\end{document}


The questions are:

Why is the font different?
Why is the hash doubled?
Why does it fails with hyperref?
How can I fix this?


The note about \footnote on page 8 of the minted doc probably applies here too. With pdflatex the font doesn't change. See also this github issue

@mbert Well, this explains the ##, but not the clash

any use of a verbatim command such as mintinline within any macro argument will only work to some extent,  if at all, having # double the font changes as it is no longer seen a #include, no time to trace what hyperef is doing here (but is has to try to stop # doub;ing)

@DavidCarlisle nameref redefines descriptionlabel to get the title.

Verbatim material should not go in the argument to other commands. In some cases \mintinline works, but you cannot expect it always does.
Solution: reduce to a case where \mintinline works inside arguments, because the code has already been absorbed verbatim.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Fails if enabled

\setmonofont{InconsolataLGCNerdFontMono}[Scale=0.8]

\NewDocumentCommand{\minteditem}{mv}{%
  \item[\mintinline{#1}{#2}]%
}

\begin{document}

\mintinline{c}|#include|

\begin{description}
  \minteditem{c}|#include| Foobar
\end{description}

\end{document}


